# Represent a Vector<ManagedAddress> output in Mandos?

Tags: multiversx

I am writing a mandos json test.

This is my method.

It returns a vector with addresses. I know with good probability this method works, I just need to test it, (I don't know how to write the test).

```rs
#[storage_mapper("match_id_to_address_map")]
#[view(getMatchIdToAddressMap)]
fn match_id_to_address_map(&self, match_id: u32) -> SingleValueMapper<Vec<ManagedAddress>>;
```

I want to write a test that makes sure it returns a vector with 2 addresses.

This is my mandos test:

```json
{
  "name": "new user with auto match",
  "steps": [
   // snipped for readability
    {
      "step": "scCall",
      "txId": "9",
      "tx": {
        "from": "address:user_one",
        "to": "sc:waiting_room",
        "function": "getMatchIdToAddressMap",
        "arguments": [
          "1"
        ],
        "gasLimit": "100000000",
        "gasPrice": "1"
      },
      "expect": {
        "out": [
          "u64:0|address:owner|address:user_one" // <- !!! IDK what to do here !!!
        ],
        "status": "",
        "logs": [],
        "gas": "*",
        "refund": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my error output:

```bash
Command line: ['/home/dan/elrondsdk/vmtools/mandos-test', '/home/dan/Elrond/SmartContracts/rooms/mandos']
Output: Scenario: deploy_and_wait.scen.json ...   ok
Scenario: duplicate_wait.scen.json ...   ok
Scenario: new_address_and_match.scen.json ...   FAIL: result mismatch. Tx 9. Want: ["u64:0|address:owner|address:user_one"]. Have: [0x6f776e65725f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f757365725f6f6e655f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f5f]
Done. Passed: 2. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0.
ERROR: some tests failed
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual decoded hex equals to

```
owner___________________________user_one________________________
```

We can see that the `u64:0` isn't represented.

I don't have the answer, but I have a lead.
Look at the serialization documentation and replace `u64:0` with the **top level-encoding**

The doc:
https://docs.multiversx.com/developers/data/serialization-overview/